# Are coefficients that are zero omitted variable bias?

Tags: regression, least-squares, omitted-variable-bias

If a regression coefficient is essentially zero, doesn't that imply that there is (massive) omitted variable bias? That is, the change must then exist in the error term.

The classic definition of OVB is that the model omits regressors that are relevant, but I in other words speculate that it also can happen through regressors with zero as coefficient.

I guess my reasoning applies to all kinds of regressions, such as OLS.

Comment: It can be zero just because there is no effect.

Comment: Essentially zero: I would just flag that coefficients have units, namely units of response / units of covariate, and often these units differ in a regression. So it's how the product of coefficient and covariate varieis that is the deal.

Comment: @MichaelM: Yes, so where is the effect showing up then? To me that means the effect is in an omitted variable and hence a large error term. Or am I thinking wrong?

Comment: How is it an "omitted variable" when it's in your regression? Consider what you're saying.

Comment: Right. My point is that if the dependent variable isn't zero but an explanatory variable is, it isn't very explanatory and the cause to the non-zero dependent variable must be somewhere else -- maybe it's not in the model, hence I call it "omitted". In short, if an explanatory variable is zero, something else must carry the effect. I would say it is the error term then. Is this thinking wrong?